# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement (Android Studio App)

Tags: android-studio, 64-bit, release, google-play-console

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement. The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [1] Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

I am trying to publish my app on Play console.
The app is build in Android Studio (Java).

However, I am facing the error seen above. Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.2.2"
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }

        splits {
            abi {
                include  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            }
        }
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "arm64-v8a":2]
                def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/libs'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    //support
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.jcodecraeer:xrecyclerview:1.6.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //vector,percent,palette
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    //equlizer
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-entypo:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.1.1'
    //data
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    //youtubeplayer

    implementation 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:androidyoutubeplayer:7.0.1'

    //Ads
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'


    implementation 'com.henryblue.mxvideoplayer:xvideoplayer:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'

    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.3'

    implementation 'com.github.fornewid:neumorphism:0.2.1'


}
```

Comment: Probably a dependency, try APK Analyzer and see if it finds anything.